# Creating array with usable elements of another array

Tags: ios, arrays

What is the way of creating array which consists with some elements of another array? I have code:

```
NSArray *columnArray = @[@"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o"];
NSMutableArray *board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 10; columnIndex ++)
{
    [board addObject:[columnArray mutableCopy]];
}

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
{
    int column1 = arc4random() % 10;//column
    int row1 = arc4random() % 10;//row

    if ([[[board objectAtIndex:column1] objectAtIndex: row1 ] isEqualToString:@"X" ])
    {
        column1=arc4random() %10;
        row1=arc4random() %10;                
    }

    [[board objectAtIndex:row1] replaceObjectAtIndex:column1   withObject:@"X"];            
}
```

How I can all the elements of the "X" placed in another array?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your sample code creates a 10x10 board, then visit 4 positions at random, and if they are X you switch their position swapping file and column. Please clarify what you mean by `How I can all the elements of the "X" placed in another array?`

Comment: I want add this 4 elements in another array

Answer (score 0):

`NSPredicate` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`: are pretty simple and easy on the eyes:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *object, NSDictionary *bind){
    return // your test here, evaluating to a BOOL
}];

NSArray *found = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: But why not just keep a list of the index paths into the arrays during the existing loop if that is the requirement?